# Allow anonymous access to custom application pages

Tags: 2013, application-pages, anonymous-authentication

I have created SharePoint Custom Application page.

I'm trying to make that application page anonymous.

So it can be viewed by any user.

For that I have did Below Workaround

- I have make web application anonymous access SharePoint 2013.
- Used unsecuredlayoutspagebase to allow anonymous access
- I have used RunWithElevatedPrivileges in code behind.
- Overriden AllowAnonymousAccess to always return true

Still it will a ask for credentials.

Please Check My Code

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;


    namespace Icalendar.Layouts.Icalendar
    {
        public partial class Icalendarfeed : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {


                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList calendarList = web.Lists["Events"];

                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                        query.ExpandRecurrence = true;

                        query.Query = "<Where>" +
                                      "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                                      "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                                      "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                                      "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
                                      "</Where>";

                        query.CalendarDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

                        SPListItemCollection calendarItems = calendarList.GetItems(query);
                        //string now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
                        string now = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now); ;
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sw = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        sw.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
                        sw.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//SharePoint MIMEDIR//EN");
                        sw.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
                        sw.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");


                        foreach (SPListItem item in calendarItems)
                        {

                           // Console.WriteLine(item["Title"] + ": starts " + item["EventDate"].ToString() + " and ends " + item["EndDate"].ToString());
                            sw.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
                            sw.AppendLine("UID;TYPE=SharePoint:" + item.ID);
                            sw.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", Convert.ToDateTime(item["EventDate"])) + "Z");
                            sw.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", Convert.ToDateTime(item["EndDate"])) + "Z");
                            sw.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + Convert.ToString(item["Location"]));
                            sw.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
                            sw.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
                            sw.AppendLine("SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:" + Convert.ToString(item["Title"]));
                            sw.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + string.Format("{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", Convert.ToDateTime(now)) + "Z");
                            sw.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION: " + item["Description"]);
                            sw.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
                          //  sw.AppendLine(string.Format("CREATED:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", DateTime.UtcNow));

                            sw.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

                        }
                        sw.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

                        string FileName = "Event.ics";


                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName);
                        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                        Response.End();



                    }
                }

                });


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this once http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/anonymous-access-sharepoint-2013-custom-application-page

Comment: Have you tried the above link.. ? Any update..?

Comment: Yes. It works. 
You can post answer

Comment: Posted the link as answer

Comment: why the whole code is within    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                { block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original post : 

[Anonymous Access: SharePoint 2013 Custom Application Page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/anonymous-access-sharepoint-2013-custom-application-page)

Try the below steps:

Step 1: Open the Central Admin and go to Manage Web Application (under Application Management) .

Step 2: Choose the Web Application you want anonymous access for and click on Authentication Provider .

[image]

Click Default,

[image]

Default

Step 3: Check Anonymous Access and Click OK.

[image]

Access 
Step 4: Open Visual Studio, create New Sharepoint Project, and add Application Page in it .

Step 5: Now remove DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" from aspx page .

[image: Ste]

Step 6: Change the Code in aspx.cs to UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase as  per your requirement below,

```
public partial class PageName: UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase  
{  
        protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess   
        {  
            get   
            {  
                return true;  
            }  
        } 
    }
```

[image]

Step 7: Open the Page in Browser (No Login Pop-up will come).

[image]